# How to use nouveau instead of intel?

Tags: laptop, nouveau

I have a laptop with Intel CPU and Nvidia GPU. I want to use nouveau but whatever I do my laptop is always using Intel's driver. How can I make it use nouveau?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because notebooks with intel and NVIDIA hybrid graphics use are using the intel graphics as default. When you you want to select which graphics to use, you have to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support. Then you can switch between the intel and the NVIDIA graphics adapter by using the NVIDIA X Server Settings application  -> PRIME Profiles.

To install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note : This assumes that you are running the latest stable Ubuntu 16.04 edition. In case you are running Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10, you have to install `nvidia-352` drivers instead of `nvidia-361`.

Comment: What if you're running Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you dont have nvidia Geforce GT(X) 900M series (960M, 970M... etc), because nouveau does not support those cards as of May 2016.

Since nouveau is loaded by default together with intel you only need to
put 1 command in a terminal once your computer has started:

```
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink nouveau Intel
```

then you only need DRI_PRIME=1 in order to run a specific program with nouveau.

```
DRI_PRIME=1 program_name
```

replace "program_name" with your applicatioin (e.g. DRI_PRIME=1 firefox )

See [here](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Optimus/) for more info

However don't expect to have good performance, since nouveau is not on par with the nvidia proprietary driver, which you can install following **cl-netbox** or an [alternative](http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.gr/2016_04_01_archive.html) way

Comment: on a box with "only intel" this gives Could not find provider with name nouveau