# how to use nouveau driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

hello i am using Ubuntu 16.04 
with gpu card of nvidia geforce 740m and nouveau driver.
im asking if there any way that i could use nouveau driver ?

i was using the proprietary one for the past year and decided to try the gallium 9 upgrade from oibaf repository.
i was using primus and optirun, and prime-switch make switching graphic easier.

is there any alternative that i can use on nouveau ?
i dont even know how to use nouveau driver nor knowing is my driver installed properly

anyway thank you beforehand :)

NB: i'd read [some answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766090/how-to-use-nouveau-instead-of-intel) but still not satisfied with it.

**Edit**
additional information. on a Laptop

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is what you are asking, but...

To switch to the nouveau driver from nvidia-xyz driver, open Software and Updates and click the Additional Drivers tab.

Select the nouveau driver from the list of video drivers, then reboot your system.

Comment: well it's not. what i mean is, like how to actually specify graphic card that run certain program or maybe switch overall used graphic card to nvidia. instead of intel (about window said graphic that used is intel).

Comment: @asembused You can't. Nvidia drivers are required for software enabled switching. Some UEFIs allow graphics selection and that feature can be used instead of doing it from the OS. Otherwise, no, you have to use Nvidia drivers.

Comment: so that means. i cant use my additional graphic card without proprietary driver.  and im stuck with using intel when using nouveau driver.
then, is there are no point of installing nouveau driver on laptop with multiple graphic card ?
sorry if im asking something really stupid